# Finding and replacing html tags conditionally from an html string

Tags: javascript, html

I have access to an html string in which I want to search for a specific set of values. So lets say I want to match something from an array...

var array1 = [value1, value2, value3]

If I find value1 in the html string, i want to add a highlight class to that value so it gets highlighted.

```js
var str = htmlString
var res = str.replace('<thead>','<thead class="highlight">');
htmlString = res
```

Using this i can highlight all the theads, but how could I write it so that I only highlight the theads that contain one of those array values inside of it?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags

Comment: Do it using dom methods. Will pull your hair out all day trying to parse the string

Comment: this var: htmlString comes from where? and it will be used where after the replace?

Comment: In the browser or on node?

Answer (score 0):

Here's a solution for browser that parses the HTML string into a DOM element, query the DOM tree and manipulate the `classList` of each selected element, then returns the HTML as a string.

```js
function addClassToElementsByTagName(html, tagName, className) {
    var tempElement = document.createElement('div');
    tempElement.innerHTML = html;

    var elements = tempElement.querySelectorAll(tagName);
    elements.forEach(function(element) {
        element.classList.add(className);
    });

    return tempElement.innerHTML;
}

var htmlString = '<table>\n\t<thead>\n\t<tr>\n\t\t<th>Column 1</th>\n\t\t<th>Column 2</th>\n\t\t<th>Column 3</th>\n\t</tr>\n\t</thead>\n</table>';

var result = addClassToElementsByTagName(htmlString, 'thead', 'highlight');

console.log(result);
```

#### Gotchas

Keep in mind that element.querySelectorAll() and element.classList.add() are not universally supported. Check out [caniuse.com](https://caniuse.com) for information regarding each feature.

Also, this is completely dependent on how the browser parses your HTML. If the HTML fails to parse or parses incorrectly, you will experience problems. The .innerHTML property also makes no guarantee that the whitespace provided in the original string will be preserved in the result.